# Angular: Override '@' property in isolate scope in link or controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive like this:

```
  .directive('myPane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.title = "Foo";
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
    };
  });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
  <my-pane title="Hello">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </my-pane>
```

And `my-pane.html`:

```
<h4>{{title}}</h4>
<div class="tab-pane" ng-transclude>
</div>
```

Now, for some reason, trying to override the `title` attribute doesn't work.

My question is, why not?

What I discovered thus far:

- This behaves the same in a `link` function
- Using `attrs.title = "Foo"` in the `link` function behaves as I'd like it to
- Using a `$timeout(function(){ $scope.title = "Foo"; })` alse behaves as I'd like it to

Relevant Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SxbGj4BZlcSX1BfkSHbq?p=preview

Comment: what is it you are trying to accomplish? are you wanting to provide a title if one is not provided on the creation, or are you always wanting to override the title attribute?

Comment: I'm trying to provide a `title` if one is not provided. This seems to work if the attribute is not set at all, but if it is set like this: `title="{{obj.title}}"` where `obj.title` is `null`, that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

you have used the `@`in your directive but this is only 1-way-databinding. You should use the `'='`, which 2-way-databinding.

change it like this :

```
.directive('myPane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.title = "Foo";
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
    };
  });
```

Comment: I don't want / need 2-way data-binding in this case. I just want to change the `title` property in the *local* directive `scope`. Shouldn't that be possible without 2-way binding?

Comment: the problem is you want to change the scope. You cant change it if it is one-way. The @ is mostly used to pass a scope through other scopes and view it.

Comment: @ is used to pas the string literal you cannot pass a scope value with it, if you pass {{scope.bob}} your value will be {{scope.bob}}

Comment: Right. My issue is when `scope.bob` is not defined. I want to be able to set `$scope.title` such that my directive template's use of `{{title}}` get interpolated with the local `$scope`.